# Swiper not working in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, swiper.js

I'm trying to integrate nolimts4web swiper into my Angular 5 project, I used in my `index.html` file

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.2.2/css/swiper.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    ...
  <script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.2.2/js/swiper.min.js"> 
  </script>
</body>
```

Put this in my HTML file:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

And initialised by putting this right before the end of the body tag in `index.html`:

```
<script>
  var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    scrollbar: {
      el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    },
  })
 </script>
```

Whats happening is that it shows the `slide 1` in the swiper however clicking next button does nothing and I can't swipe, basically actions are not working.

Comment: the usage for nolimts4web is totally different from what you are trying they have used <ks-swiper-containe> their own module for this are you using the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use this [library](https://github.com/JayChase/ngx-useful-swiper) to avoid `Swiper` init before html is loaded.

---- UPDATE 1 ----

in my opinion, your issue is related to the life cycle of your HTML, that means, Swiper is initialize before html are loaded/interpreted by the browser. To avoid this issue, you can use linked library or just create component who looks like :

```
// Don't forget to declare Global variable related to Swiper.
declare var Swiper: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'swiper',
  template: `
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
`
})
export class SwiperComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef
    ) {}

    //[...]

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        /**
         * - Here you are 100% sure, html is present on DOM, Swiper is initialize and is able to find your DOM element.
         * - Swiper constructor accept DOMElement as parameter, i recommand this approch to optimize DOM parsing.
         * - Because you store Swiper instance as attribute, you will be able to control Swiper by javascript. 
        **/
        this.swiper = new Swiper(this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.swiper-container'), {
            //Here you can provide Swiper config
        });
    }
}
```

[Online sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-da1phu?file=app%2Fswiper.component.ts)

Comment: This won't be consider as answer since it doesn't provide more details than the link. If you have any more details then you can update your answer with it. Else this is just a comment to this question.

Comment: @TheDictator i have update my answer and add online sample.

Comment: I am getting this error in console: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at Swiper.updateSize` any idea?

Comment: You should probably create another topic with runnable example of your facing issue. If you ping me here, i will try to find solution for you.

Comment: @Yanis-git where is `this.swiper` declared ? Lint throws error in this line

Comment: yes you should declare property with [swiper type](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/swiper)

Comment: I am using your instantiation of swiper, although TS/Ionic at times it's like black magic. Can you explain why if I do this.swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", 
Per the swiper API/demos sample code.
I get an array of 2 swipers?  Thank you.

Comment: @Yanis-git in stackblitz demo, click (next, prev) buttons still not working. How I can fixed them ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for the answer for a long time.

In my case, I had an outdated swiper package. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-useful-swiper).

I uninstalled it and installed this npm: https://github.com/JayChase/ngx-useful-swiper (last version) for angular 7 then I followed the examples and now everything's okay.